# Row scroll and hide under fixed row above

Tags: html, css

I have two rows, the top contains text, and the one underneath contains a set of cards. Is it possible to have the cards scroll under the text so that they are no longer visible?

```
<div id="main-container" class="container">
  <div id="title-row-small" class="row">
    <div class="container center">
      <div class="show-on-small-only hide-on-med-and-up">
        <p id="title-text">Scott and Viki</p>
        <p id="date-text">23/06/18</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="card-row" class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6 l4">
      <a href="#" onclick="$('#agenda-modal').modal('open');">
        <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="./assets/SVSunset.jpg">
          <span id="card-title" class="card-title">Agenda</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The small amount of CSS I've added allows the cards to scroll underneath but they are no longer positioned under the text y position, the text is no longer centered and scaling correctly and I have no idea how to make the cards disappear behind the text instead.

```
  #card-row {
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
  }

  #title-text {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-family: "Calling Angels Personal Use";
    text-shadow: 4px 4px 12px #fff;
  }

  #date-text {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 45px;
    font-family: "Strawberry Whipped Cream";
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #fff;
  }
```

[image: Heres an image of it]

I would appreciate any help. I'm sure this is basic but I'm just learning at the moment and googling didn't help me much as you can see.

Thanks

Comment: Throw together a quick jsfiddle or better yet, just use the snippets option on here.

Comment: Im trying, but its not too simple with angular and typescript :)

Comment: So you when you scroll, you want the text to be on top on have the image scroll underneath of the text, right? Do you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/oevc502g/

Comment: Thats it! Is there any way to have the text background transparent and the cards disappear behind that "transparency"?

Comment: Like so you can see the image scrolling behind the text? https://jsfiddle.net/oevc502g/1/

Comment: More like its going behind the text and background at that point. Is this possible without adding an image of the patterned background as the text background?

Comment: Also why is text no longer centered when applying a fixed position to the row?